# Can not to reach (ping,ssh) Ubuntu host from local network (WLAN). Is it due to router or linux setup?

Tags: networking, ubuntu, wireless-networking, router

I'm trying to do the simplest thing: connect 2 Ubuntu boxes via SSH to copy files over, over a WLAN router, using their IPs.
The ubuntus can't see each other either by ping or ssh. Sshd is running, internet access from both machines are fine, they are just not seeing any local ips.

I can ping a Windows box on the same LAN (no ssh there).
I was looking for some firewall settings (as I've done in the past), but it's Ubuntu 20.04 and not so familiar with state of the art now.
Suspected it's some router setting issue, but then tested pinging that windows box, that ip was visible (after selecting "Make this PC visible for other pcs on the network").

Also tried to connect 2 ubuntus with adhoc wifi using network manager, but all those options that worked in the past are gone or not working either.. couldn't find up to date documentation either.
Any hints would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The issue ended up being firewall related indeed. Although, as I said I didn't see any obvious firewall settings on the 19.04 and 20.04 - as I read about 'ufw' but that was not installed, it turns out that this new (to me) service was running on both boxes: firewalld (https://computingforgeeks.com/install-and-use-firewalld-on-ubuntu-18-04-ubuntu-16-04/ )

So the solution was to move the wifi interface from the 'drop' zone on to the 'home' zone:
sudo firewall-cmd --zone=home --change-interface=wlp61s0